# C++ Pointer to Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I want to have a pointer to a constant, and pass its address to a function that will increment it.

```
int f1(const int **ptr) {
    int n = **ptr; //use pointer
    (*ptr)++; //increment pointer
    return n;
}

void foo(const int *data) {
    const int *p = data;
    const int n = f1(&p); //error: invalid conversion from ‘const int**’ to ‘int**’
                          //error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int LevelLoader::readWord(byte**)’


}
```

How do I declare the pointers?

Comment: Why are you wanting to change a constant?  Also you may want to consider use references

Comment: Why are you assigning `f1`'s return value to `n` when it's `void`?

Comment: oops. it should return n

Comment: I can't reproduce those errors. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I compiled the edited version of your code in VC2008, and it compiled just fine. Considering that your errors mention things that you haven't shown us (what is "LevelLoader::readWord", and why haven't you posted it in your question), I'd suggest posting the _actual_ code and not a facsimile of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
int f1(const int *& ptr) {
  int n = *ptr;
  ++ptr; 
  return n;
}

void foo(const int *data) {
  const int *p = data;
  const int n = f1(p); 
}
```

instead.

The error message indicates that `LevelLoader::readWord` doesn't take a `const byte**`.

Comment: @richb : When I wrote it the type of `f1` was `void`. After that correction it does the same as the pointer to pointer variant, which also compiles fine, but I think it's cleaner to have a pointer reference. Two indirections are hard to handle in (at least my) mind. So I think we should get rid of it in C++, since it is a bad habit inherited from C.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
const int *data;
```

is a pointer to a *constant* integer. That means that you are not allowed to change the data pointed to by `data`. You can read and copy the data, but you can't do:

```
(*data) = 5;
```

That's illegal in C++ because it was declared `const int *`.

If you take the address of a `const int *`, you get a `const int **`, which is a pointer to a pointer to a *constant* integer. So you still cannot change the integer. Any attempt to do so will cause the compiler to complain.

If you want to be able to change the integer, then `foo` and `f1` should not take `const int *` values. They should take `int *` values.

---

> I don't want to modify the constant. I want to modify the pointer to it (p in foo())

So, you're given a pointer. And you want to increment the *pointer*. So just do so:

```
void foo(const int *data) {
    const int *p = data;
    data++;
}
```

You have incremented the pointer. This will not affect the caller to `foo`, as the pointer itself is copied by value.

Comment: I want to increment it in the f1() function, so I need to pass the pointer's address

Comment: eh? he's not trying to modify the const int, just the pointer.

Comment: I want to increment to pointer in f1(), so I need to pass its address

Answer (score 1):

Check again, this code is correct. It shouldn't generate the errors you claim.

EDIT: You fixed the void problem so answer amended accordingly.